Drop multiple entities reference the same different entity
Say I have two different types of entities referencing the same third type, e.g
public class Person {
    @OneToOne(
        optional = false,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Address address;

    // ...
}

public class PaymentConnection {
    @OneToOne(
        optional = false,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Address address;

    // ...
}

public class Address {
    // No "backlink" to either Person nor PaymentConnection
}

public class Root {
    @OneToOne(
        optional = false,
        cascadeType = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne(
        optional = false,
        cascadeType = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private PaymentConnection paymentConnection;
}

(I know that PaymentConnection, Person and Root probably shouldn't be connected like shown here, this is just for illustration purposes)
How would I go about deleting an instance of Root and all it's child entities (using panache repositories)?
If I do just
rootRepository.delete(root);

I get an exception

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "adresse_id" of relation "person" violates not-null constraint

So I delete the person first manually, i.e.
personRepository.delete(root.getPerson());
rootRepository.delete(root);

I get the same exception, just this time it couldn't delete PaymentConnection, so I do the same for it
personRepository.delete(root.getPerson());
paymentConnectionRepository.delete(root.getPaymentConnection());
rootRepository.delete(root);

But I still get

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "adresse_id" of relation "payment_connection" violates not-null constraint

These exceptions are also only being thrown once the transaction is commited, not on the actual lines where I'm deleting my instance of Root.

You have specified
    @OneToOne(
        optional = false,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Address address;

By using orphanRemoval the remove operation is cascaded to the address. In order to remove the address all references to an address have to be first removed. So hibernate will first remove the reference by setting address_id to null, then delete the Address and at last the PaymentConnection.
You may want to modify the database to allow deferred checks for the involved foreign key constraints.

Sadly, Postgres doesn't support deferring NOT NULL constraints. But why does Hibernate set a non-nullable field to null for orphan removal, why not just DELETE FROM person ... then check if anything references Address and if not delete it as well?
